# How to use box2d objects in libGDX engine

Tags: android, box2d, libgdx

Please provide me with some links, tutorials.
I can know box2d and libGDX but i don't know how to use it together.
Thanks Muniek

Answer (score 0):

This is in the libgdx wiki, so is updated when needed.

http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/PhysicsBox2D